# Maintain coldfusion j2ee session using URL parameters with cookies disabled

Tags: session, url, cookies, parameters, coldfusion

I cannot seem to get my session to preserve itself with J2EE enabled and browser cookies disabled using SESSION.URLToken to append the session information to a link.

I need a very specific solution to these exact criteria because of the following limitations:

1. We have over 2500 templates and are trying to avoid adding `URLSessionFormat()` to every link.
2. We already have an internal variable that we include on every link (`link.cfm?#OurVariable#`) that is set from a single login verification template. We'd like to reuse that variable to insert the `SESSION.URLToken` when necessary.
3. We'd prefer to use J2EE.  This code already works fine with CF Session Management.
4. 1/3 of our users do not allow cookies and we cannot force them to.  They are in a very locked down environment with old browsers.

Now, the test case.....

**Application.cfc:**

```
<cfcomponent>  
    <cfset this.name = "test" />  
    <cfset this.sessionManagement = true>  
    <cfset this.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan(2,0,0,0)>  
</cfcomponent>
```

**Index.cfm:**

```
<CFOUTPUT>
<CFSET SESSION.Testme = 123 />
<a href="#URLSessionFormat("index2.cfm?somevar=test")#">link 1</a>
or this
<a href="index2.cfm?#session.urltoken#&somevar=test">link 2</a>
</CFOUTPUT>
```

**Index2.cfm:**

```
<CFDUMP VAR="#SESSION#">
```

With my browser cookies turned off and J2EE session variables turned on, "link 1" will display the "TestMe" key in the cfdump.  "link 2" will not.

With my browser cookies turned off and J2EE session variables turned off (defaulted to Coldfusion CFID/CFToken Session management), both links display the "TestMe" key as expected.

Please consider my 4 pieces of criteria above when offering solutions as to why CF Session Management works as expected while J2EE does not.

Thanks for any insight that you can provide!

Comment: What do the resulting URLs look like in both scenarios? I presume they are different and that is why you are seeing different results with the JEE sessions. Based on that we may be able to determine a solution. What version of ColdFusion are you on?

Comment: Why can't you use the `URLSessionFormat()` function? It seems to do exactly what you are wanting and works based on your test.

Comment: As indicated in my original post, we are trying to avoid going through 2500 templates.  That's why we aren't using `URLSessionFormat()`, unless we need to.

Comment: As for the rendered URL's, they are obviously different between the functioning and nonfunctioning methods.  And I understand why they are different.  What I can't understand is why the documentation says that a method will work when it doesn't.

Comment: Forgive me for all of the comments.  I'm having a very difficult time getting the StackOverflow formatting to work.  Double spaces for bridge returns doesn't seem to work for me.  
This sentence should be on a new line.

Comment: According to the [CF10 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fef.html), in the section pertaining to passing sessions without cookies, it states, "To use ColdFusion client variables and J2EE session variables, pass the CFID, CFToken, and jsessionid values in URLs."

Comment: I suppose that I will just do a global replace of ".cfm" with ".cfm#SessionInfo#" and then generate the jsession info when needed and populate the `#SessionInfo#` variable.  That would take care of our immediate concerns.  We can then slowly migrate to `URLSessionFormat()` as we move forward.

Comment: That was the point I was trying to make earlier, if you are going to modify the code anyway, why not use `URLSessionFormat()` which seems to do exactly what you want?  Instead of replacing `.cfm` with `.cfm#SessionInfo#` replace `index.cfm` with `#UrlSessionFormat('index.cfm')#`? I get that there may be varying strings you will need to search and replace but do it right now instead of battling this again later.  My .02

Comment: The strings vary wildly from page to page. There are 2500 templates so let's say that 50% of them have links that point to each other.  And then, for each of those, there are a random assortment of potential URL parameters. There is no shortcut here for adding URLSessionFormat().  Not with our codebase.

However, I was able to put my plan into place in about 3  minutes.

Thank you for your suggestions.  I would still consider this question unanswered, however, because at the core I was wondering why a documented function of Coldfusion was not working as described.